# R barplot with grouping

Tags: r

I checked ggplot specs and looks like I need transpose my data to build bar plot, or there is still an option to use with that df, so I actually can use column names in groupings, I mocked up image for demo below, on ggplot still can't get where we do groupings, or we can list them with comma ? Tx all

```
df1 <-  data.frame(yy=2017,  F1=23, F2=40, F3=4)
df2 <-  data.frame(yy=2018,  F1=16, F2=90, F3=8)
df <- rbind(df1,df2)
df 
    yy F1 F2 F3
1 2017 23 40  4
2 2018 16 90  8

ggplot(df, aes(F1, yy)) +   ## this is just bad sample
  geom_bar(aes(fill = yy), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: You need to reshape your dataset in order to have `F1, F2, F3` as a variable and use in as your x axis.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <-  data.frame(yy=2017,  F1=23, F2=40, F3=4)
df2 <-  data.frame(yy=2018,  F1=16, F2=90, F3=8)
df <- rbind(df1,df2)

df %>% 
  gather(type,value,-yy) %>%           # reshape data
  mutate(yy = factor(yy)) %>%          # update variable to a factor
  ggplot(aes(type, value, fill=yy)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Antonio !!  Muchas Gracias!!